# Oracle error - ORA-00936: missing expression with replace function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to make a query when a user searches for **احمد** without the **Hamza (ء)** it returns the results with `hamzam` and the results without `hamza` as follows:

```
select * 
  from EMPLOYEES  
 Where (Replace(Replace(Replace(first_name, 'ا', 'أ'), 'و','ؤ'), 'ي', 'ى') 
        like (Replace(Replace(Replace(['احمد'], 'ا', 'أ'), 'و','ؤ'),'ى','ي')
```

but I am getting the exception: `Oracle error - ORA-00936: missing expression`

please advise how to fix it.

Comment: Please post "plain text" code (and format it), not images.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name issue is that the query looks corrupted and not well formatted when i paste it here

Comment: have you looked at [`translate`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

You missed 2 parentheses:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM EMPLOYEES  
 WHERE (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(first_name, 'ا', 'أ'), 'و','ؤ'), 'ي', 'ى'))
        LIKE (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(['احمد'], 'ا', 'أ'), 'و','ؤ'),'ى','ي'))
```

Comment: when i use above query i get the error `invalid relational operator`

Comment: Hmmm... I guess you can't have REPLACE() on both sides of LIKE

Comment: do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: 1) You don't use any wildcard characters, as far as I can see, why don't you use `=`? 2) Just noticed - what are those '[' characters in your query? 3) Try `TRANSLATE()`

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-00936: missing expression`  always indicates a syntax error.  There are several bloomers in your posted code.

1. The number of `)` must match the number of `(`.
2. `[` is not a recognised character in Oracle SQL.  It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with them, so it's difficult to know how to suggest you fix this, but you need to get rid of them somehow.
3. The `,(` construct is wrong.

Or rather apparent bloomers.  Because when I attempted to correct your code  the editor reversed my changes e.g.  `)` turned back to `(`.  When I pasted it into an ASCII editor I saw this ...

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(first_name, '?', '?'), '?','?'), '?', '?')
```

... which gives the correct count of `)` and the correct nesting of REPLACE() calls.

Hypothesis: some kind of character set mistranslation.   So the question is, is the SO editor introducing this corruption or are you experiencing this in your client too?

Incidentally the right side of the operation in ASCII is

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(['????'], '?', '?'), '?','?'),'?','?'))
```

So those rogue `[` `]` are real (I think) and you must remove them.  Given that the other "errors" may just be artefacts of the SO Editor I think those square brackets are the thing you should focus on.